# Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

Tags: mysql

**質問**

・mysqldのバージョンを確認しようとしたら、下記メッセージが表示されました
・どういう意味でしょうか？
・ルートでmysqldを動かすには、セキュイリティの[マニュアル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/security.html)を読む？

```
# mysqld --version
```

> Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out
>   how to run mysqld as root!

---

**環境**
・MySQL5.7
・一般ユーザではバージョン表示されるのですが…

```
$ mysqld --version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 5.7 の mysqld は root では実行出来ません。

メッセージの内容は「マニュアルの [Security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/security.html) セクションから 『rootでmysqldを動かす方法』を探し出して見てください。」という感じでしょうか。

ただ、マニュアルを読んでも root で動かす方法は書かれてないと思います。
その代わり 「root では実行しないでください」といった旨の記述が見つかります。

マニュアルに誘導するためにそういうメッセージなのかなと推測します。